Opening a GTK-4 font chooser with a specific font selected
I have code with the following two lines. (See below for full working example.)
/* Instantiate a font button */
GtkWidget *font_button = gtk_font_button_new ();

/* Set the font to an existing font on the system */
gtk_font_chooser_set_font(GTK_FONT_CHOOSER(font_button),"Monospace Bold 12");

These two lines open the font chooser, but the first font in the list is selected. I want the font Monospace Bold to be selected. How do I achieve this effect? TYIA.

Full working example
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
/* Compile with gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk4` main.c `pkg-config --libs gtk4` */

void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer data) {
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);

    /* Instantiate a font button */
    GtkWidget *font_button = gtk_font_button_new ();

    /* Set the font to an existing font on the system */
    gtk_font_chooser_set_font(GTK_FONT_CHOOSER(font_button),"Monospace Bold 12");

    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), font_button);
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), box);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    GtkApplication *app;

    app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return 1;
}


There is already one example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78990144/22768315
The point is that the string must follow exactly the following scheme:
"[FAMILY-LIST] [STYLE-OPTIONS] [SIZE] [VARIATIONS]"
Further explanations can be found in the documentation of GTK4:
https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/type_func.FontDescription.from_string.html
Have fun testing.

Thanks for this. That code sample uses GtkFontDialog, which is available since GTK 4.10. I'm languishing in Debian, which provides 4.8. Nevertheless this gives me a very good start toward the solution. Will advise.

A conversation on discourse.gnome.org confirmed that GTK 4.8 has a bug that was subsequently fixed, probably in 4.10. @Holger provided the correct answer.
